# Evernote php cloud sdk Update note contents and note tag Names

Tags: php, evernote

I am facing problem in php cloud sdk to get note tags. I can get tag guids but can't find real tags (tag names).

I am also facing problem in updating notes content (append new text to existing note).

```
        $note_store=$this->evernote->getUserNotestore();

        $note = $note_store->getNote($accessToken, $results[0]->guid, true, false, false, false);
    
        $note->content='<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd"><en-note><div>'.$content.'</div><div> new Contents Here </div></en-note>';
;

        //$note->content = new \Evernote\Model\PlainTextNoteContent($content."<br> New message to append.");

        $res=$note_store->updateNote($this->profile['sSocialToken'], $note);

        echo "<pre>",print_r($res);die();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have tag guids, you can use [NoteStore#getTag](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getTag). For the note content update, I'm not sure about what error you've got so I don't exactly know what the problem is. If you get an EDAM error with authentication token, you are using the wrong one. Otherwise, what you should be looking at is probably the note content format. Here's the [doc](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php) for that.

Comment: Another option for tags is to call getNoteTagNames ( https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteTagNames).

Comment: @PhilSeeman i tried getNoteTagNames but it gives me empty response.

Comment: The second parameter of the `getNoteTagNames` is a Note guid, while a tag guid is used for `getTag`. If you just want to get tag names on a specific note, I guess `getNoteTagNames` is better as @PhilSeeman suggested.